# How to filter non-resolvable URIs on a SPARQL query?

Tags: uri, sparql, rdf, triplestore

Is it possibe to filter out results that contains a non-resolvable URI within the SPARQL query?

An example: I'm making the following query (endpoint: http://linkeddata.systems:8890/sparql):

```
PREFIX RO: <http://www.obofoundry.org/ro/ro.owl#>
PREFIX SIO: <http://semanticscience.org/resource/>
PREFIX EDAM:  <http://edamontology.org/>
PREFIX PHIO: <http://linkeddata.systems/ontologies/SemanticPHIBase#>
PREFIX PUBMED:  <http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/pubmed/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX up:  <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?disn_1 ?label ?rel ?valor 
WHERE { ?disn_1 ?rel ?valor . ?disn_1 rdfs:label ?label FILTER(( ?disn_1 = <http://linkeddata.systems/SemanticPHIBase/Resource/host/HOST_00561>))}
```

In the results, as you can see there is in ?valor variable a triple that contains a non-resolvable URI (text: /hostncbitaxid/). I would like to know if there is some specific FILTER that can be added in the SPARQL query to remove those results with non-resolvable URIs.

I'm having problems with the API that I'm using to process these results in C# because it is returning an exception due to non-resolvable URIs so I would like to filter them out in the SPARQL query (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that it's not resolvable?  RDF doesn't have a concept of a "relative URI", all the URIs are resolved relative to something (and perhaps to what is an implementation detail in some cases), so you end up with absolute URIs. In the HTML results from that endpoint, I get `http://linkeddata.systems:8890/hostncbitaxid/`, and that could easily be resolvable.

That said, if you are ending up with results that include non-absolute URIs, and you want to filter those out, you could use some heuristics to do that.  For instance, if you only want URIs beginning with **http**, you can do that.  E.g., here's a query that returns two values for **?uri**:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select * where {
  values ?uri { <http://www.example.org/> </foobar> }
}
```

```
-----------------------------
| uri                       |
=============================
| <http://www.example.org/> |
| <file:///foobar>          |
-----------------------------
```

(Notice that the relative URI **/foobar** got resolved as a **file://** URI.)  You can keep only **http** URIs with a **filter**:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select * where {
  values ?uri { <http://www.example.org/> </foobar> }
  filter strstarts(str(?uri), "http")
}
```

```
-----------------------------
| uri                       |
=============================
| <http://www.example.org/> |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your reply. I already did something like that, but the problem is that it filters out one of the results that it is not a URI (concretely, the one where ?valor is ""Host - null - HOST_00561"@en". Is it possible to filter out only those values of ?valor with type "URI" and that, as you said, does not start with http?

Comment: @alejandrorg Sure, just change the filter to `filter (!isURI(?x) || strstarts(str(?x), "http"))`.

Answer (score 2):

The query returns (SPARQL results in JSON format):

```
"valor": { "type": "uri", "value": "/hostncbitaxid/" }}
```

This is bad data - it must be an absolute URI in RDF. Presumably the data is bad.  You can remove it in the query as [@joshua-taylor shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490650/1281433).